# Can I access an AWS RDS read replica directly from Internet?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds, amazon-vpc

Or what is the same, is possible assign a public IP address to my RDS read replicas? My read replicas end points answer with private IPs right now, even they are in a VPC subnet with an AWS Internet Gateway. In fact, my master RDS (multi AZ) was in that same subnet days ago (before it move automatically due to some changes in instance type I did) and I access perfectly from Internet, but I can't access read replicas now.

**EDIT:**

Using Amazon Web Console one can change some replica options but *Publicly Accessible* is not one of them. When you create read replicas you can specify allow *Publicly Accessible* what give to the replica a public IP address, but what I want is change that option in an already created read replica. So far what I know is that using AWS Web Console you can't do that (that option don't appear between the available options to edit), but seem to me that using command line you can edit that parameter neither [rds-modify-db-instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/CommandLineReference/CLIReference-cmd-ModifyDBInstance.html)

Comment: Don't they give you a DNS endpoint for them?

Comment: Sure, and as I said "My read replicas end points answer with private IPs"

Comment: I thought I remember reading somewhere that you can attach a public ip to them

Comment: @DrewKhoury After created them? At creation time one can set the *Publicly Accessible* option and that attach a public IP to the read replica, but what about assign a public IP after created them? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I'm not sure I've never tried. Why don't you give it a go, or maybe try posting a question on the AWS forums also.

Comment: @DrewKhoury I don't give it a go because I don't know how give it a go, that is precisely my question, how do that. Of course I already put a [question](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=154667&tstart=0) at AWS forum, but not reply so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is impossible, a kind of AWS limitation. What seem to be the [lowest/rawest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyDBInstance.html) way to interact with AWS (on which RDS Web Console and RDS Command Line are based on) not have a way to change that option.